# How should Christianity respond to the person who defames it?

Tags: ethics, punishment

In a Christian country (where the Christian law is obeyed), if a person insults Jesus, makes fun of him and defames the Bible, How should the Government, Church and Christians respond (according to Christianity)? Is there a punishment like death, torture or at least deportation?

PS: I am not sure if the tag is relevant, feel free to edit.

Comment: I've attempted to answer this question with a broad framework of 'Christian' according to the question you've asked, but the actual site rules specify that asking general questions like this without specifying a specific denominational or doctrinal framework are actually off-topic (refer to our [help centre](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) for more details on this). So your question may be closed unless you can edit is to include a particular perspective you are seeking (eg Roman Catholic, Baptist etc.).

Comment: Your question makes the assumption that God can be insulted. This is impossible. Only a god, can be insulted. A religion can be insulted and for that reason it would be protected in some countries. The problem with your question is in 'how should ...?'. No single answer there. Maybe change it to 'how would a specific group (Malawi/Switzerland or Catholics/Jehovah's Witnesses or farmers in Iowa) respond?

Comment: Also, there is truly no such thing as a definition of a Christian country according to the law (ex. Christian) obeyed there. A Christian country is one in which the majority of the citizens and the rulers are Christian, and no doubt their public actions MIGHT be guided by their faith, but there is nothing that constitutes a detailed Christian public law.

Comment: What is this "Christian law" you speak of?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It seems you've mistaken the purpose of this site.  I hope you choose to participate further, but before you do, please see [How we're different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help).  Also, specific to this and your other recent question, consider [Is it valid to ask if “Christianity” teaches anything?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-it-valid-to-ask-if-christianity-teaches-anything)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many different Christian perspectives and some may disagree, but it's arguable that at least a majority of Christians would agree that:

**A Christian should respond as Jesus would and according to what He taught**:

> 38 “You have heard that it was said, ‘Eye for eye, and tooth for tooth.’ 39 But I tell you, do not resist an evil person. If anyone slaps you on the right cheek, turn to them the other cheek also. 40 And if anyone wants to sue you and take your shirt, hand over your coat as well. 41 If anyone forces you to go one mile, go with them two miles. 42 Give to the one who asks you, and do not turn away from the one who wants to borrow from you. 43 “You have heard that it was said, ‘Love your neighbor and hate your enemy.’ 44 But I tell you, love your enemies and pray for those who persecute you, 45 that you may be children of your Father in heaven. He causes his sun to rise on the evil and the good, and sends rain on the righteous and the unrighteous. 46 If you love those who love you, what reward will you get? Are not even the tax collectors doing that? 47 And if you greet only your own people, what are you doing more than others? Do not even pagans do that? 48 Be perfect, therefore, as your heavenly Father is perfect. - [Matthew 5:38-48 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%205&version=NIV)

So, we should not retaliate, or even resist them; but pray and show love according to the will of our Father in heaven.

This is further explained by Paul, one of the early followers of Jesus:

> 17 Do not repay anyone evil for evil. Be careful to do what is right in the eyes of everyone. 18 If it is possible, as far as it depends on you, live at peace with everyone. 19 Do not take revenge, my dear friends, but leave room for God’s wrath, for it is written: “It is mine to avenge; I will repay,” says the Lord. 20 On the contrary:
>
> “If your enemy is hungry, feed him;
>       if he is thirsty, give him something to drink.
>   In doing this, you will heap burning coals on his head.”
>
> 21 Do not be overcome by evil, but overcome evil with good. - [Romans 12:17-21 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rom%2012&version=NIV)

So we should treat them well and leave it for God to deal with them. The government is a quite different matter - it has the authority (given by God ultimately, and the will of it's people secondarily) to make laws that are just and fair for the benefit of it's citizens.  If the government decides it is in the interest of public order to enact a law that prevents the sort of behaviour you mention, then that is a matter for the government.  Christians have differing views on what should be the relation between the Church and the state, but most views seek to interpret what Jesus meant by:

> Jesus said, “My kingdom is not of this world. If it were, my servants would fight to prevent my arrest by the Jewish leaders. But now my kingdom is from another place.” - [John 18:36 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%2018%3A36&version=NIV)

And will argue for at least some form of separation between the two - just how much and what that practically means is worked out in different ways in different contexts and is the subject of ongoing debate.

***Summary:*** Most Christians would argue that we should not retaliate against those who seek to insult, mock or defame either Christ, Christians or the Bible; in fact we should pray for them, love them and leave them in God's hands to judge with the hope that they will repent and find mercy from Him. What the governement does to them is not necessarily a Christian's (or the Churches) business except insomuch as their citizenship or office requires them to draw up, vote on, enact or enforce the laws of the land.

Comment: No punishment???? I am stunned!!!

Comment: @HashirOmer We are called to faith in our God as the just judge - He will punish evil-doers who do not repent in His good timing and far more effectively than humans can ever do.

Comment: @HashirOmer. With right you can be stunned. The answer is idealistic. I know that people in different parts of the world experience Christianity differently. (the Lord's Army etc) I do not think it is a good idea to spit on a Cross in Mexico - you might lose your head. And I'm not sure a gay pride parade will go down well in Zimbabwe. Christianity is a bit complex . . .

Comment: @gideonmarx The key word is *should* (ie not *would*).

Comment: It is idealistic only in its definition of Christian. Many persons, myself included, call themselves Christians, but compartmentalize their Christianity from everyday life. Many Christians keep their Christianity and its symbols as primarily a source of identity, and would for example fight for Christian symbols remaining public, with their very actions however running contrary to Christian teachings.

Bruised reed's answer is not idealistic in what a Christian would do.

It is not that Christianity is a bit complex as much as Christians are. Many Christians are only nominally so.

Comment: What's missing is that Christians should also keep publicly showing respect for Jesus and the Bible. Sure people mock Christianity all the time. Act unphased and it's a positive witness for Jesus and the Bible.

Comment: @HashirOmer fundamentally Christianity relies on a concept that is basically unknown in Islam: it is grace. While Islam has forgiveness, it is not as central as submission. Fundamentally, the Gospel is Good News that we don't have to follow rules- God's love is so great that he reached out to us even when we could not reach out to him. We are imperfect. We sin. We fall short of what God intended. But God demonstrated his love for us in this: while we were yet sinners, he died for us. If that is the case, how could we not forgive those who sin against us?

Comment: @Hashir Omer, Christianity (properly practiced) is not a national law. The New Testament presents the church as God's people within an ungodly nation (Philippians 2:15). Its understood that the government will normally oppose God's true will, and we are called to suffer persecution for Christ's name, not to persecute others. (Luke 6:22, 2 Timothy 3:12, John 15:18, 1 John 3:13)

Comment: @HashirOmer what were you expecting [295C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasphemy_law_in_Pakistan)???

Comment: @AffableGeek. Islam does not have submission as a central tenant? Are you trying to be funny?

Comment: @gideonmarx From http://www.thereligionofpeace.com/pages/myths-of-islam.htm#islammeanspeace: "The root word for Islam is “al-Silm,” which means “submission” or “surrender.”  There is no disagreement about this among Islamic scholars."

Comment: Can everyone that does not know what the word Islam means stay away from these questions. You are an embarrassment to Christianity.

Comment: Art. #5:  WHAT DOES “ISLAM” MEAN?  The Arabic word Islam simply means “submission”, and derives from a word meaning “peace”.  In a religious context it means complete submission to the will of God.  ... http://allaboutmuhammad.com/what-does-lsquoislamrsquo-mean.html

Comment: @AffableGeek. Maybe I misunderstood your sentence. 'While Islam has forgiveness, it is not as central as submission'. As central as who or what?

Comment: (The second one is a less biased source.)   So, I know Islam pretty well. I've lived in Muslim countries, I've known imams, and I've read parts of the Qu'ran. Islam is a religion which emphasizes submission to God's will (i.e. doing the right things) as the key to "doing it right". Some Christians will say there is no such thing as grace or forgiveness in Islam.  That statement is a little bit hyperbolic, but the gist isn't off the mark. Even an imam will agree that grace is much more distinctively Christian, and that Islam is about doing the right things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17377/discussion-between-affable-geek-and-gideon-marx).

Comment: Nope. Do not know how to use chat but, submission is a word that includes many things, including automatic forgiveness, reward, punishment,justice etc, in Islam. It is way beyond the word 'submission' as you use it in English. To a Muslim your sentence would simply make no sense. They have no uncertainty. That is why they appeal. You submit - you are forgiven. End of the story.